# Get referer-app-link or the source app from where applink is clicked for Cordova Android App without using the Bolts framework

Tags: android, cordova, applinks

I can open my app through facebook but I am unable to go back to facebook.

Comment: If you're on Android, why not just use the back button?

Comment: Back Button doesn't work, it just shows me the previous loading page of the app.

Comment: What I mean is, you should make the back button work in your app so that it goes back to the app that called you, rather than just loading another page in your app.